# Why does the Java ternary operator cause the compiler to think this String will be empty?

Tags: java, android, ternary-operator

```
String colorString = myObject.getColor(); // "0000ff"
colorString = colorString == null ? "#44FF0000" : "#44" + colorString;
int myColor = Color.parseColor(colorString); // Length must be at least 1
```

[`Color.parseColor(String colorString)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)) from the `android.graphics` library is annotated with `@Size(min=1)` from [`android.annotation.Size`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Size.html). Why does the compiler think that the resulting string of the above ternary operation might be empty while the below code works?

```
 String colorString = myObject.getColor(); // "0000ff"
 if (colorString == null) {
     colorString = "44FF0000";
 } else {
     colorString = "#44" + colorString;
 }
 int myColor = Color.parseColor(colorString); // all's good
```

Comment: what *compiler error* are you getting?

Comment: *library is annotated with @Size(min=1) from the Bean Validation model.* ... no, with `android.annotation.Size`

Comment: my bad, the compiler error is `Length must be at least 1`

Comment: It is rather Lint hint

Comment: I would create a bug report and then either suppress the warning or use the if/else statement.